# addClass("test") give error: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In console I have:

```
$(".myCssClass")[0].parentNode
<li><span class="myCssClass">some text</span></li>
```

I want to add css class for parent `span`, for tag `<li>`

I tried like this:

```
$(".myCssClass")[0].parentNode.addClass("test")
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I use Jquery 1.5.2

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`addClass` is a method of jQuery objects. When you use `$(".myCssClass")[0]`, you have the real element, not the jQuery wrapper.

Then, you can:

- Wrap it to a jQuery object again:

  ```
  $($(".myCssClass")[0].parentNode).addClass("test")
  ```
- Only work with jQuery objects:

  ```
  $(".myCssClass").eq(0).parent().addClass("test")
  ```
- Add class with plain JavaScript (not supported on old browsers):

  ```
  $(".myCssClass")[0].parentNode.classList.add("test")
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.parent()`

```
$(".myCssClass").parent().addClass("test")
```

`.addClass()` can only be used against jQuery selectors.

***Alternative solution*** (wouldn't recommend this over the top mentioned solution but for the sake of completion)

`$(".myCssClass")[0].parentNode` is not a jQuery object, to convert into one you need to wrap with `$()` like this

`$($(".myCssClass")[0].parentNode)` //jQuery selector

now `addClass()`, `$($(".myCssClass")[0].parentNode).addClass("test")`