# How can you get the data attribute of a class member using the classname as a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I have code as follows,

```
<div class="apples" data-id="1"></div>
<div class="apples" data-id="2" id="secondDiv"></div>
```

Each div has an onClick event listener. When I click a div, something unique happens depending on which div was clicked. For example,

```
$(".apples")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("first apple was clicked"); 
});
```

My problem is regarding the **data attribute**. On click, I wish to know the data-attribute of the div that was clicked.

This works,

`$("#secondDiv").data("id");  //returns 2`

This doesn't,

`$(".apples")[1].data("id");  //returns TypeError: $(...)[1].data is not a function`

This is useless,

`$(".apples").data("id");   //returns 1`

How can I get the data-attribute of a div using the classname? 
The actual number of divs in the code is too large for giving each a unique HTML id to be practical.

Thanks

Comment: This is more or less like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23228760/1529630)

Comment: If you want an easier way of dealing with vanilla-js without he jQuery try: https://github.com/eorroe/NodeList.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) is a jQuery method, only available on jQuery object wrappers.

`$(".apples")` is a jQuery object wrapper, and thus has the `data` method.

`$(".apples")[1]` is a DOM object, and thus does not have the `data` method.

Then, you can

- Wrap the DOM object in a jQuery object again:

  ```js
  $($(".apples")[1]).data("id");
  ```
- Use [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), which will return only the desired element in a jQuery wrapper:

  ```js
  $(".apples").eq(1).data("id");
  ```
- Use vanilla-js to read the data attribute:

  ```js
  $(".apples")[1].dataset.id;
  $(".apples")[1].getAttribute('data-id');
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Would have never guessed the distinction between the two.

Answer (score 3):

The below will log the data-id attribute value for the element with the apple css class that is clicked on.:

```
 $(".apples").on("click", function(){
      console.log($(this).data("id")); 
 });
```

Comment: Oh! Cool thanks! Will accept as answer (after the 10min wait period)  =)

Comment: sure, glad to help out :)

Comment: @JetBlue: Unless you have a specific need to store the id in jQuery's global cache, consider using `$(this).attr("data-id")` or even better `this.getAttribute("data-id")`. It's faster and doesn't add any memory overhead.

Comment: @BhavO: Yes it does. Using `.get(0)` is basically the same as `[0]`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I know I said earlier I'd accept yours as the answer but @Oriol answer is more detailed as to what's happening and why.

Comment: sure, glad to help out

Answer (score 1):

Here's my code! Hope you like it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = 'es'>
    <head>
        <title> MY TEST </title>
        <meta charset = 'utf-8'>
        <style>
            .apples{
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="apples" data-id="1" id = 'firstDiv'>APPLE 1</div>
        <br>
        <div class="apples" data-id="2" id= 'secondDiv'>APPLE 2</div>
        <script>

            //Getting the references to the "apples"
            var apple1 = document.getElementById('firstDiv');
            var apple2 = document.getElementById('secondDiv');

            //Adding the events listeners
            apple1.addEventListener('click', doTheMagic);
            apple2.addEventListener('click', doTheMagic)

            function doTheMagic(e){
                alert('You clicked an apple ');
                var dataApple = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
                alert('This apple has a value for his data-id of: ' + dataApple);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```